# How can I prevent any connection to a given IP using Windows Firewall on Microsoft Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall

How can I prevent any connection to a given IP using Windows Firewall on Microsoft Windows 7?

For example, I would like to prevent any connection to the IP `192.168.2.221`. I created one inbound and one outbound custom rules that I tried to parameterized to block any connection to the IP, as shown in the screenshot below (the two rules named `NAS`), but the computer cana still communicated with this IP. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing the remote address on the local addres field.

You need to change this to the Remote Address field to make it work. Because your local ip address is not that of the NAS, there's nothing to block.

The rules should therefore look as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `NAS` is a device you want to block from that Windows computer? "Local address" is misleading -- it refers to your computer's local IP address, not an external device (which may or may not be on your local network).

Putting the IP `192.168.2.221` into the "remote address" scope instead, and "local address" as `Any` should work.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed got mixed up by the wordings local vs remote.